# pip3 install mlagents causing error because of h5py>=2.9.0

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, ml-agent

I'm trying to install this package to use it with unity

mlagents 0.29.0
https://pypi.org/project/mlagents/

pip3 install mlagents

Note: i have a mac

I'm getting this error

ERROR: Some build dependencies for h5py>=2.9.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/c7/9410b3802f456c702f6e0ccebf82e628f42a30921f61a232e26e424d95d4/h5py-3.5.0.tar.gz (from mlagents) conflict with the backend dependencies: numpy==1.22.3 is incompatible with numpy ==1.19.3; python_version>='3.9'.

I also tried this command
pip3 install mlagents --use-feature=2020-resolver

didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by running this command

`pip3.8 install mlagents`

pip3.8 not pip3

Answer (score 1):

Found out that h5py removed setup dependencies and newer version now should be able to be installed. Try this:

```
pip3 install h5py==3.7.0
```

and then

```
pip3 install mlagents
```

Comment: ok trying it, will check

Comment: I made them, now I'm running this command ```pip3 install mlagents```

Comment: Didn't work, same error

Comment: try to install h5py==3.7.0 separately and then install mlagents

Comment: also didn't work

Comment: could you please show the error or it is the same?

Comment: I installed it alone, then I installed the mlagents and didn't work, same error

Comment: same error
```
RROR: Some build dependencies for h5py>=2.9.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/c7/9410b3802f456c702f6e0ccebf82e628f42a30921f61a232e26e424d95d4/h5py-3.5.0.tar.gz (from mlagents) conflict with the backend dependencies: numpy==1.22.3 is incompatible with numpy ==1.19.3; python_version>='3.9'.
```

Comment: I'm trying this now pip3.8 ```pip3.8 install mlagents```

Comment: it works, ```pip3.8 install mlagents```

Comment: How can I give you a points?

Comment: there is no need, i haven't solved your problem